# Oracle find closest Wednesday to first of each month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this tricky Oracle requirement in which I need to find, for each month, the closest Wednesday to the 1st of each month. I know how to find first Wednesday of each month, but I'm struggling with this because it could be on the previous month.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
WITH aux ( first_month ) AS (
    SELECT
        trunc(add_months(DATE '2021-01-01', + level - 1), 'MM')
    FROM
        dual
    CONNECT BY
        level <= 12
)
SELECT
    first_month,
    trunc(first_month - 7, 'IW') + 3 last_thu,
    trunc(first_month + 7, 'IW') + 3 next_thu
FROM
    aux
```

Comment: Do you know what day the first of that month is? Then you know how many days before or after that nearest Wednesday is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take next or previous WEDNESDAY depending on distance from the first of month

```
WITH aux ( first_month ) AS (
    SELECT
        trunc(add_months(DATE '2021-01-01', + level - 1), 'MM')
    FROM
        dual
    CONNECT BY
        level <= 12
)
SELECT CASE WHEN NEXT_DAY(first_month ,'WEDNESDAY') - first_month >= 4 
       THEN NEXT_DAY(first_month - 7,'WEDNESDAY')
       ELSE NEXT_DAY(first_month ,'WEDNESDAY') END closest
FROM aux
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use below query -

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'WEDNESDAY') - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')) < (TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') - NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1)) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'WEDNESDAY'))
                 THEN NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 'WEDNESDAY')
            ELSE
                NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1)) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'WEDNESDAY')
       END NEAREST_WEDNESDAY
  FROM DUAL;
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/37c8b8/10)